# connect by prior query is slow

Tags: sql

Am having performance issue on a SQL using "CONNECT BY PRIOR".
With about 480 records in the table temp_hierarchy, SQL using connect by prior is very slow and is taking about 8 to 10 mins.

I believe the data has long cycle records like 1->2, 2->3, and 3->1 which is leading to slowness.

This is the query am using.

```
    select  distinct t.id, t.parent_id, t.child_id,
    leveling, level as check_level
    from temp_hierarchy t
    start with t.parent_id = 0
    connect by nocycle PRIOR t.child_id = t.parent_id;
```

The table structure is as below:

desc temp_hierarchy

```
   Name                 Null Type                        
   -----                ------------

   ID                        NUMBER(19)                  
   PARENT_ID                 NUMBER(19)                  
   CHILD_ID                  NUMBER(19)                  
   LEVELING                  NUMBER(19)
```

Indexes are defined on columns parent_id and child_id.

Any suggestion to improve the performance of the query would be of great help. Or how to find the long cycle records? the pseudo column CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE is returning all 0.

Comment: I am not sure that this is important to your question, but it is not clear why you have in the table the `id` field and the `child_id` field. How are these two fields different?

Comment: id column is just a running sequence for the records in temp_hierarchy table. it is just for identifying unique records.